# What is causing the site to call Facebook for scripts and images?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, firefox-developer-tools

We have a ASP.NET MVC website that contains no JavaScript file or image referenced from Facebook.net or Facebook.com.

Yet Firefox developer tools is showing these calls are happening and causing the site to load slowly.

How do I find out what is causing these calls?

[image: e t]

Comment: Do you have anything like a "Like us on Facebook" link on a page? Nobody is going to be able to help you without access to your actual code.

Comment: Could be a browser plugin doing it maybe?

Comment: @Pointy I have already mentioned the website contains no reference to script or image to FB. In other words there are no Like Us or similar plugins on our website. I guess I need to ask if Developer Tools can tell me the line of code in the website that is causing the request

Comment: Well the browser won't do that by itself. It's your codebase; you should be able to search it to find references. If your code loads *other* fragments (from ad servers or something like that) then it code be that that's where the references are coming from. Again, nobody can help you find something in code they can't see.

Answer (score 1):

It was coming from Google Tag Manager JavaScript code. Even though there were no hard coded references to Facebook in the project, they were present in the Google Tag Manager admin console.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of transactions are usually connected to Facebook Like/Share/Follow buttons (Facebook plugins in general) embedded in the webpage.

Based on the few transactions, which you shared, I would say that you've added a Facebook Page/Group Plugin to your webpage.